# Ansible to create NIC bonding

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-2.x

I had to do NIC bonding using Ansible. I have 4 NIC on the machine & tried this play, which I have taken from [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/nmcli_module.html)

```
---

#ansible-playbook -i hosts/groups.dat -l vertica07.abc.com vertica-network.yml -e '{ "bond1_ip" : "10.253.1.7" }' -u root -k

- hosts: vertica
  gather_facts: true
  sudo: yes

  vars:
    - bond1_ip: "{{ bond1_ip }}"
    - bond1_gw: "x.x.x.x"

    #bond vars
    - nmcli_bond:
         - {conn_name: 'bond0', ip4: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}", gw4: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.gateway }}", mode: 'active-backup'}
         - {conn_name: 'bond1', ip4: "{{ bond1_ip }}", gw4: 'bond1_gw', mode: 'active-backup'}

    - nmcli_bond_slave:
         - {conn_name: 'p1p1', ifname: 'p1p1', master: 'bond0'}
         - {conn_name: 'p1p2', ifname: 'p1p2', master: 'bond0'}
         - {conn_name: 'p2p1', ifname: 'p2p1', master: 'bond1'}
         - {conn_name: 'p2p2', ifname: 'p2p2', master: 'bond1'}

    #ethernet vars
    - nmcli_ethernet:
         - {conn_name: 'p1p1', ifname: 'p1p1', ip4: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}", gw4: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.gateway }}"}
         - {conn_name: 'p1p2', ifname: 'p1p2', ip4: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}", gw4: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.gateway }}"}
         - {conn_name: 'p2p1', ifname: 'p2p1', ip4: "{{ bond1_ip }}", gw4: "{{ bond1_gw }}"}
         - {conn_name: 'p2p2', ifname: 'p2p2', ip4: "{{ bond1_ip }}", gw4: "{{ bond1_gw }}"}

  tasks:

  - name: install needed network manager libs
    yum: name={{ item }} state=installed
    with_items:
      - NetworkManager-glib
      - libnm-qt-devel.x86_64
      - nm-connection-editor.x86_64
      - libsemanage-python
      - policycoreutils-python


  - name: try nmcli add bond - conn_name only & ip4 gw4 mode
    nmcli: type=bond conn_name={{item.conn_name}} ip4={{item.ip4}} gw4={{item.gw4}} mode={{item.mode}} state=present
    with_items:
      - "{{nmcli_bond}}"


  - name: try nmcli add bond-slave
    nmcli: type=bond-slave conn_name={{item.conn_name}} ifname={{item.ifname}} master={{item.master}} state=present
    with_items:
      - "{{nmcli_bond_slave}}"
```

But its failing on

```
TASK [try nmcli add bond - conn_name only & ip4 gw4 mode] **********************
failed: [vertica07.abc.com] => (item={u'conn_name': u'bond0', u'mode': u'active-backup', u'ip4': u'10.100.1.7', u'gw4': u'bond0_gw'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"conn_name": "bond0", "gw4": "bond0_gw", "ip4": "10.100.1.7", "mode": "active-backup"}, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1459368691.93-148688989216143/nmcli\", line 385, in <module>\r\n    from gi.repository import NetworkManager, NMClient\r\nImportError: No module named gi.repository\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
failed: [vertica07.abc.com] => (item={u'conn_name': u'bond1', u'mode': u'active-backup', u'ip4': u'10.253.1.7', u'gw4': u'bond1_gw'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"conn_name": "bond1", "gw4": "bond1_gw", "ip4": "10.253.1.7", "mode": "active-backup"}, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1459368692.4-174709839763552/nmcli\", line 385, in <module>\r\n    from gi.repository import NetworkManager, NMClient\r\nImportError: No module named gi.repository\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

I am on Ansible 2.0.1 and doing Network bonding on Centos 6.3. At present I am running this just on single host.

Whats I am missing here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
 - libnm-gtk-devel.x86_64
```

Instead of:

```
 - libnm-qt-devel.x86_64
```

I'm currently using ansible 2.0.1 in my CentOS 7 server.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Python-gobject in CentOs try with:

```
yum install NetworkManager-glib 

yum install pygobject2
```

https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject

The module needs that pyhton dependence.

Comment: Still failing after installing pygobject2

Comment: What is you python version? Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: I changed my answer try installing NetworkManager-glib  that works for me.

Comment: I do have NetworkManager-glib installed on the target machine

Answer (score 0):

Had similar error in RHEL 7 and its fixed by installing PyGObject2 like Raul Mentions above

[root@node1 ~]# rpm -qa --last | head
pygobject2-2.28.6-11.el7.x86_64